# How to construct timestamp_tz from timestamp_ntz using time zone names

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake how do I combine a time zone name with a timestone_ntz field to create a timestamp_tz value?

In Oracle it's:

```
SELECT from_tz(<timestamp_col>, <timezone_name>) 
FROM <my_table>;
```

All the Snowflake examples I have seen seem to require me to specify the time zone as an offset in terms of hours and/or set a session parameter.

I don't want to have to specify time zone offsets in hours. I don't wish to use session parameters as I want to control the loading at field/record, not session, level.

I think something along the lines of this does what I want but it seems there must be a better way:

```
SELECT convert_timezone('Europe/London', 'Europe/London', <timestamp_ntz_col>);
```

I also am aware of the `timestamp_tz_from_parts()` function, but that seems a bit 'heavy'.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: What's the actual data type for TS_COL (i.e. the default data type for "timestamp"), I'm guessing TIMESTAMP_NTZ? This is the default specified in your TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING session parameter.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths ...both stored in varchar fields...

Comment: _"both stored in varchar fields"_  A very serious design flaw.  You don't have a timestamp, you have a string of characters that, when displayed on a screen or printed on a piece of paper, is recognized by humans as _representing_ a timestamp.  But to the database, the varchar '2021-09-21 17:49:37.00000' is fundamentally no different than 'yadayadayadayada'.  And the FROM__TZ function takes a TIMESTAMP as its first parameter, not a varchar.

Answer (score 0):

> I also am aware of the timestamp_tz_from_parts() function, but that
> seems a bit 'heavy'.

I don't think it's heavy, and you can create your own function to reduce the complexity of your main queries:

```
create or replace function mergetz( ts varchar, tz varchar ) 
returns timestamp_tz as
$$
TIMESTAMP_TZ_FROM_PARTS(
YEAR( ts::date ),
MONTH( ts::date ),
DAY( ts::date ),  
HOUR( ts::datetime ),    
MINUTE( ts::datetime ),    
SECOND( ts::datetime ),
0, -- nanoseconds
tz ) 
$$
;

SELECT mergetz( ts, tz) 
from values 
('2019-01-01 12:00:00','America/New_York'),
('2019-01-01 12:15:00','Europe/London') tmp (ts, tz );

+-------------------------------+
|       MERGETZ( TS, TZ)        |
+-------------------------------+
| 2019-01-01 12:00:00.000 -0500 |
| 2019-01-01 12:15:00.000 +0000 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: That looks doable, but I find it slightly odd that there is no way of doing it (as far as I can see) via a Snowflake native function. I also find it slightly odd that the 3 parameter version of convert_timezone returns a timestamp_ntz and not a timestamp_tz.

Comment: When used in the 3 parameter form, CONVERT_TIMEZONE is a function to convert one TIMEZONE_NTZ value into another TIMEZONE_NTZ value that has been adjusted by the numbers of hours difference between the two timezones specified, i.e. the output is of the same data type as the input.  This is different from the 2 parameter form which although it takes any timestamp type as input always maps it to TIMESTAMP_TZ (if input is NTZ then the system TZ is assumed), applies the timezone adjustement and outputs a TIMEZONE_TZ.